# maps not loading, can anyone help me {Fluttter}

Tags: flutter

maps not loading, can anyone help me {Fluttter}

[App showing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWT4O.png)

It appears that the error you're encountering is related to the Google Maps initialization or configuration. Specifically, the error message suggests a problem with the 'maps' property being accessed on an undefined object. This often happens if the Google Maps API is not initialized properly or if there's an issue with the plugin setup.
Here are a few potential troubleshooting steps i can tried:

Restart your app and hot restart your Flutter development environment.
Invalidate caches and restart your IDE.
Double-check the API key, ensuring that it's correctly configured and does not have any restrictions that might prevent the maps from loading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the "Maps JavaScript API" as the documentation states?
Also check the limitations of web version of the package.

refer: [web-specific documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_web)